# bootstrap pull-right adding extra space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using pull-right on a div that sits inside a container div but for some when I use a pull right on the div it makes the div wider so that it isn't flush with the right side of the page.  Ive used Chrome to inspect the element but I can't figure out where this extra width is coming from.  It isn't the padding or the margin the container just seems to be wider?

Problem can be seen here at the top of the page where all the social media icons are.
http://puntachivosurfcamp.com/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="pull-right">
      <a><img/></a>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would adding the class `text-right` in addition to `pull-right` be what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer that did achieve the desired look but I'm still curious about where the width was coming from, the same thing happened if I tried to pull the individual links right as well they ended up being wider than the images.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such extra space but the text is just aligned to the left although the container you are talking about is `pull-right` but the objects in it aren't. So:

1. Apply `text-right` as well on your `pull-right` div to align the text to right side :)
2. Apply `pull-right` to every object present in the div aka social media icons *(but I recommend the first approach)*

**Explanation:**

The width of the container is greater then the width of all the object in it so when the objects in the container will be left aligned it will show us as if some extra space was present on the right side but as soon as we align the text to the right we see that now the space has been vanished and the objects have now come on the extreme right of your page.

Comment: I just applied text-right to the container and removed the div altogether.  However when the pull-right class is removed from the div with the images the div is no wider than the images (no space to the right).  If pull-right is applied then the div is wider than all the images.